# Jquery POST method doesn't work on IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post

My Jquery (version: 1.8.1) code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#Vehicle-make').change(function() {
        $.post(
            '/cakeMotors/ModelNames/viewList/' ,
            { make_id : $('#Vehicle-make').val() } ,
            function(data) {
                $('#Vehicle-model').html(data); 
            }   
        );
    });
});
```

- Works fine on FF and Chrome, even checked that the server response to the POST request is 200.
- #Vehicle-make and #Vehicle-model are both form selects.
- It is not a cross-domain request, so I think that's not the problem.
- When I erase the $.post() and put something like an alert inside the .change event, it works fine! So, i guess IE is not messing with that either.

What could it be?

Comment: Shot in the dark here - try wrapping the **key** (`make_id`), of the JSON you are sending in single quotes.

Comment: Add a delegate to handle an AJAX error to see what IE's problem is and update us with that info.

Comment: Thanks for all the replys. I chained the error callback after the $post method, like this: .error(function() { alert(jqxhr.statusText); }) and I obtained the following: 403 - Forbidden. How is that possible if I'm  working i the localhost?

Comment: I just figured it. The mistake was from my own stupidity! There was a duplicated select tag in my code that IE8 didn't take very well. Thanks for everybody's attention!

Answer (score 1):

IE is caching ajax urls. Try to put at the end of url parameter of time ticks  (new Date).getTime()

This will prevene IE to cache result.

And yes, this is shot in the dark :)